# Initialize training set in Pandas with Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm doing some research on Random Forests algorithm and build a classifier with the instruction from [this post](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/random-forests-classifier-python)

**I have the following segment of code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Import train_test_split function
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data=pd.DataFrame({
'sepal length':iris.data[:,0],
'sepal width':iris.data[:,1],
'petal length':iris.data[:,2],
'petal width':iris.data[:,3],
'species':iris.target}

X=data[['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']]  # Features
y=data['species']  # Labels

# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3) # 70% training and 30% test
```

I'm using `iris` dataset imported from `sklearn`. However, whenever I run this code I have the following **error**:

```
File "<ipython-input-11-71013f105652>", line 12
X=data[['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']]  # Features
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think that this error is because of the fact that I have initialised `X` list which acted as `Feature` the wrong way.

**THE PROBLEM** is that it was a typo in the code

Comment: It's because you've not closed the parentheses on your DataFrame. `'species':iris.target` -> `'species':iris.target})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you are missing the ending "})" of the pd.DataFrame()

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'sepal length':iris.data[:,0],
    'sepal width':iris.data[:,1],
    'petal length':iris.data[:,2],
    'petal width':iris.data[:,3],
    'species':iris.target
})
```